How does returning an array from a function with a class type know what constructor to call C++
I'm struggling to understand what is happening with this code. It works, but I can't seem to understand why.
Also struggling how to phrase this questions, so tried to give us much detail as possible.
I'm using a class out of the FastLED library for Arduino compatible devices (I'm using ESP32).
I can create a gradient pallet using the following code:
CRGBPalette16 tmpPalTest()
{
    uint8_t xyz[8];

    xyz[0] = 0;  // anchor of first color - must be zero
    xyz[1] = 0;
    xyz[2] = 255; // Full Green
    xyz[3] = 0;



    xyz[4] = 255;  // anchor of last color - must be 255
    xyz[5] = 255; // Full Red
    xyz[6] = 0;
    xyz[7] = 0;

    return xyz;
}


CRGBPallet16 test = tmpPalTest(); // Correctly produces a green to red gradient. 

Class in question:
class CRGBPalette16 {
public:
    CRGB entries[16];  
 
    CRGBPalette16() {};
 
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGB& c00,const CRGB& c01,const CRGB& c02,const CRGB& c03,
                    const CRGB& c04,const CRGB& c05,const CRGB& c06,const CRGB& c07,
                    const CRGB& c08,const CRGB& c09,const CRGB& c10,const CRGB& c11,
                    const CRGB& c12,const CRGB& c13,const CRGB& c14,const CRGB& c15 )
    {
        entries[0]=c00; entries[1]=c01; entries[2]=c02; entries[3]=c03;
        entries[4]=c04; entries[5]=c05; entries[6]=c06; entries[7]=c07;
        entries[8]=c08; entries[9]=c09; entries[10]=c10; entries[11]=c11;
        entries[12]=c12; entries[13]=c13; entries[14]=c14; entries[15]=c15;
    };
 
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGBPalette16& rhs)
    {
        memmove8( (void *) &(entries[0]), &(rhs.entries[0]), sizeof( entries));
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGB rhs[16])
    {
        memmove8( (void *) &(entries[0]), &(rhs[0]), sizeof( entries));
    }
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( const CRGBPalette16& rhs)
    {
        memmove8( (void *) &(entries[0]), &(rhs.entries[0]), sizeof( entries));
        return *this;
    }
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( const CRGB rhs[16])
    {
        memmove8( (void *) &(entries[0]), &(rhs[0]), sizeof( entries));
        return *this;
    }
 
    CRGBPalette16( const CHSVPalette16& rhs)
    {
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            entries[i] = rhs.entries[i]; // implicit HSV-to-RGB conversion
        }
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CHSV rhs[16])
    {
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            entries[i] = rhs[i]; // implicit HSV-to-RGB conversion
        }
    }
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( const CHSVPalette16& rhs)
    {
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            entries[i] = rhs.entries[i]; // implicit HSV-to-RGB conversion
        }
        return *this;
    }
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( const CHSV rhs[16])
    {
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            entries[i] = rhs[i]; // implicit HSV-to-RGB conversion
        }
        return *this;
    }
 
    CRGBPalette16( const TProgmemRGBPalette16& rhs)
    {
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            entries[i] =  FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR( rhs + i);
        }
    }
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( const TProgmemRGBPalette16& rhs)
    {
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            entries[i] =  FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR( rhs + i);
        }
        return *this;
    }
 
    bool operator==( const CRGBPalette16 &rhs) const
    {
        const uint8_t* p = (const uint8_t*)(&(this->entries[0]));
        const uint8_t* q = (const uint8_t*)(&(rhs.entries[0]));
        if( p == q) return true;
        for( uint8_t i = 0; i < (sizeof( entries)); ++i) {
            if( *p != *q) return false;
            ++p;
            ++q;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool operator!=( const CRGBPalette16 &rhs) const
    {
        return !( *this == rhs);
    }
    inline CRGB& operator[] (uint8_t x) __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        return entries[x];
    }
    inline const CRGB& operator[] (uint8_t x) const __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        return entries[x];
    }
 
    inline CRGB& operator[] (int x) __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        return entries[(uint8_t)x];
    }
    inline const CRGB& operator[] (int x) const __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        return entries[(uint8_t)x];
    }
 
    operator CRGB*()
    {
        return &(entries[0]);
    }
 
    CRGBPalette16( const CHSV& c1)
    {
        fill_solid( &(entries[0]), 16, c1);
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CHSV& c1, const CHSV& c2)
    {
        fill_gradient( &(entries[0]), 16, c1, c2);
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CHSV& c1, const CHSV& c2, const CHSV& c3)
    {
        fill_gradient( &(entries[0]), 16, c1, c2, c3);
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CHSV& c1, const CHSV& c2, const CHSV& c3, const CHSV& c4)
    {
        fill_gradient( &(entries[0]), 16, c1, c2, c3, c4);
    }
 
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGB& c1)
    {
        fill_solid( &(entries[0]), 16, c1);
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGB& c1, const CRGB& c2)
    {
        fill_gradient_RGB( &(entries[0]), 16, c1, c2);
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGB& c1, const CRGB& c2, const CRGB& c3)
    {
        fill_gradient_RGB( &(entries[0]), 16, c1, c2, c3);
    }
    CRGBPalette16( const CRGB& c1, const CRGB& c2, const CRGB& c3, const CRGB& c4)
    {
        fill_gradient_RGB( &(entries[0]), 16, c1, c2, c3, c4);
    }
 
    CRGBPalette16( TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_bytes progpal )
    {
        *this = progpal;
    }
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_bytes progpal )
    {
        TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion* progent = (TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion*)(progpal);
        TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion u;
 
        // Count entries
        uint16_t count = 0;
        do {
            u.dword = FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR(progent + count);
            ++count;
        } while ( u.index != 255);
 
        int8_t lastSlotUsed = -1;
 
        u.dword = FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR( progent);
        CRGB rgbstart( u.r, u.g, u.b);
 
        int indexstart = 0;
        uint8_t istart8 = 0;
        uint8_t iend8 = 0;
        while( indexstart < 255) {
            ++progent;
            u.dword = FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR( progent);
            int indexend  = u.index;
            CRGB rgbend( u.r, u.g, u.b);
            istart8 = indexstart / 16;
            iend8   = indexend   / 16;
            if( count < 16) {
                if( (istart8 <= lastSlotUsed) && (lastSlotUsed < 15)) {
                    istart8 = lastSlotUsed + 1;
                    if( iend8 < istart8) {
                        iend8 = istart8;
                    }
                }
                lastSlotUsed = iend8;
            }
            fill_gradient_RGB( &(entries[0]), istart8, rgbstart, iend8, rgbend);
            indexstart = indexend;
            rgbstart = rgbend;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    CRGBPalette16& loadDynamicGradientPalette( TDynamicRGBGradientPalette_bytes gpal )
    {
        TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion* ent = (TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion*)(gpal);
        TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion u;
 
        // Count entries
        uint16_t count = 0;
        do {
            u = *(ent + count);
            ++count;
        } while ( u.index != 255);
 
        int8_t lastSlotUsed = -1;
 
 
        u = *ent;
        CRGB rgbstart( u.r, u.g, u.b);
 
        int indexstart = 0;
        uint8_t istart8 = 0;
        uint8_t iend8 = 0;
        while( indexstart < 255) {
            ++ent;
            u = *ent;
            int indexend  = u.index;
            CRGB rgbend( u.r, u.g, u.b);
            istart8 = indexstart / 16;
            iend8   = indexend   / 16;
            if( count < 16) {
                if( (istart8 <= lastSlotUsed) && (lastSlotUsed < 15)) {
                    istart8 = lastSlotUsed + 1;
                    if( iend8 < istart8) {
                        iend8 = istart8;
                    }
                }
                lastSlotUsed = iend8;
            }
            fill_gradient_RGB( &(entries[0]), istart8, rgbstart, iend8, rgbend);
            indexstart = indexend;
            rgbstart = rgbend;
        }
        return *this;
    }
 
};

Full source code here:
https://fastled.io/docs/colorutils_8h_source.html#l00904
I would think it works by creating a class of type CRGBPalette16 with it's internal variable CRGB entries[16]; filled with my uint8_t values. Like if I cast from one data type to another.. That wouldn't work, as CRGB is under the hood basically uint8_t[3] and I'm pass array with 4 items (index, r, g, b), so it would throw off the RGB colors off by 1 for each color.
So what looks like happening is somehow it's calling this constructor:
  CRGBPalette16( TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_bytes progpal )
    {
        *this = progpal;
    }


which then calls
    CRGBPalette16& operator=( TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_bytes progpal )
    {
        TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion* progent = (TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion*)(progpal);
        TRGBGradientPaletteEntryUnion u;
 
        // Count entries
        uint16_t count = 0;
        do {
            u.dword = FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR(progent + count);
            ++count;
        } while ( u.index != 255);
 
        int8_t lastSlotUsed = -1;
 
        u.dword = FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR( progent);
        CRGB rgbstart( u.r, u.g, u.b);
 
        int indexstart = 0;
        uint8_t istart8 = 0;
        uint8_t iend8 = 0;
        while( indexstart < 255) {
            ++progent;
            u.dword = FL_PGM_READ_DWORD_NEAR( progent);
            int indexend  = u.index;
            CRGB rgbend( u.r, u.g, u.b);
            istart8 = indexstart / 16;
            iend8   = indexend   / 16;
            if( count < 16) {
                if( (istart8 <= lastSlotUsed) && (lastSlotUsed < 15)) {
                    istart8 = lastSlotUsed + 1;
                    if( iend8 < istart8) {
                        iend8 = istart8;
                    }
                }
                lastSlotUsed = iend8;
            }
            fill_gradient_RGB( &(entries[0]), istart8, rgbstart, iend8, rgbend);
            indexstart = indexend;
            rgbstart = rgbend;
        }
        return *this;
    }




So what I don't understand is how the compiler knows I want to call: CRGBPalette16( TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_bytes progpal ) when all I'm just returning a UInt8_t array with type CRGBPalette16 from a function?

the compiler doesnt know what you want, it doesnt read minds ;). It applies overload resolution

Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part. For example, you have a lot of code not related to the problem, and miss some code that are (like CRGB).

The type TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_bytes is an alias for uint8_t *, which is the best match for construction from a value of type uint8_t[8].

I see, so in C++, return xyz gets converted into return CRGBPalette16(xyz) not return (CRGBPalette16)xyz as I was thinking it might. I'm coming from C# so I would be have to do return new CRGBPalette16(xyz) to get that same effect

@JamesWilliams here, its all the same https://godbolt.org/z/xYjWs8KW8. Its a non-explicit converting constructor, which can be used for implicit conversions

@JamesWilliams CRGBPalette16(xyz)  and (CRGBPalette16) xyz are equivalent in this case.

Thank you, you've lead me onto here for further reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor great example as well

@JamesWilliams generally though, (CRGBPalette16)xyz should be avoided (use a proper cast instead if you must), and conversions are recommended to be explicit rather than implicit.
